# How to read all grand child of all child without knowing the key of parent and grand child in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

I want to read the `child list of address` child `for all Users` in the firebase database and show them into a single recycler view.

I don't know the key of the child of Users also a key of the child of address.

[image: Img]

do this for all parents

Comment: If you provide more information might we can help you to build structure for Database. Otherwise you need to retrieve them all in recyclerview and show.

Answer (score 1):

> - get the key of the adress
> - based on addrss get details of address
> - use nested observer

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference addressRef = rootRef.child("bbKskDdFMIct8fuh6sWsTWsTWkk6Kn2").child("address");  // set main key and address
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();  // get address child key
            Log.d(TAG, key);

            // add one more observer that give you key response 

            DatabaseReference childRef = rootRef.child("bbKskDdFMIct8fuh6sWsTWsTWkk6Kn2").child("address").child(key);  // set main key and address                 
            // add new listent that give you detail of address 
            childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(addressValueListner);   

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
addressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```